# Naming multi syllables field in a table

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, naming-conventions

Sometimes I want to name a field in a table and this field is composed of a number of syllables!

I wonder how to select the most meaningful name in that case.

For example:

```
number of successions.
number of weekends
```

Should I write it:

- NumberOfSuccessions
- NumOfSuccessions
- NumberSuccession
- SuccessionNumbers

---

I care about my attribute naming because I'll deliver this to another developer and I want to get it smoothly.

Comment: By 'field', did you mean 'column', and by 'syllable' did you mean 'word'? If so, in Oracle you would use underscores to separate words e.g. `number_of_successions` or `succession_count`, because camel case is not persisted in the dictionary and so it would be stored as `NUMBEROFSUCCESSIONS` which is not very readable.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson : Using underscores is not recommended in my case because I use `EntityFramework` which internally uses `Pluralization` and `Singularization`  ! and I'm so upset because the capitalization in oracle

Comment: I've never heard of Entity Framework. Is some jumped-up UI tool seriously dictating to you how to design the schema? I'm sorry to hear that.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson It's the `ORM` of microsoft

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I don't why you downvote :(

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it is kind of an opinion-based question.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Thanks, I try to be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select the first one, i.e. "NumberOfSuccessions" as that looks neat. It is always good to avoid short forms and keep the name as simple as plain english, wherever possible. Also avoid spaces as you have already done, just to make life simple.

Comment: Please mark it as the answer if it did so.